# Filtering data.frame values

Tags: r

I'm leaning R and I'm a little lost. I have a data.frame with 13 columns. My 13th column is ratings for a brand. However I have a lot of bad data in that column. How would I filter that column? For example, for any product a rating of 1-5 in fine, but in my .csv file, there are blanks, words like INC, words like "bar", etc. So I only want to use rows with a rating 1-5 in them and not use the row that has anything else. So do I have to write a function? Use ddply? Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2):

I'll just make a simple 2-column data set.

```
dd <- data.frame(
    band=letters[1:8],
    rating=c("1","5","INC","3","bar",NA,"2","1")
)
#   band  col
# 1    a    1
# 2    b    5
# 3    c  INC
# 4    d    3
# 5    e  bar
# 6    f <NA>
# 7    g    2
# 8    h    1
```

I can subset this to only values in `rating` that are 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 with

```
dd[which(as.numeric(as.character(dd$rating)) %in% 1:5), ]
#   band col
# 1    a   1
# 2    b   5
# 4    d   3
# 7    g   2
# 8    h   1
```

So your column is probably a factor in R. So I use as.character to get the labels, and then use as.numeric to get the numeric values of that label. If the label is not a number, it will be turned into an `NA` value. Not I check which values are in the set `1:5` and i wrap that in a `which` in order to drop the NA values. Then I use this numeric vector to subset the data.frame to just the rows i'm interested in. You can reassign this result to a new variable. You will get a warning about `NA` values in match, but that's OK and what we expect.

Comment: To avoid the warning, you could instead convert `1:5` to characters, e.g. `subset(dd, rating %in% as.character(1:5))`.

Comment: Very good point @flodel. That would a much better solution for integer values. You'd really only have to do what i did if you had non-integer numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

First, welcome to the best open-source software on the planet.

Okay, here's an example.  Take this messy data frame `x`

```
> x <- data.frame(a = c("foo", "bar", "2", "INC", "5"), 
                  b = c("1", "NO", "foo", "3", "no"))
> x
#     a   b
# 1 foo   1
# 2 bar  NO
# 3   2 foo
# 4 INC   3
# 5   5  no
```

We can find the numeric values numerous different ways, but I like `grep`.  The following shows us that rows 1 and 4 of column b contain numeric values

```
> grep('[0-9]+', as.character(x$b))
# [1] 1 4
```

The we can save that as `numsb`

```
> numsb <- grep('[0-9]+', as.character(x$b))
```

And subset the data frame for those rows with vector operations

```
> x[numsb, ]
#     a b
# 1 foo 1
# 4 INC 3
```

Notice that you could also just put `grep` into the above subset.  But I'll use `grepl`, the logical `grep`, for column a.`

```
> x[grepl('[0-9]+', as.character(x$a)), ]
#   a   b
# 3 2 foo
# 5 5  no
```

The same follows for the other columns. You'll need to coerce the columns to class `numeric` if you need them for calculations

```
> z <- x[numsb,]
> z$b <- as.numeric(z$b)
```

and the same for the other subsets